# UWP win10 IOT access missed calls

Tags: uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I want to install win10 IOT on a raspberry pi 3 and then access the missed call history, when someone called (like win10 shows them in the action center) and also if someone is calling my phone at the moment. So the raspberry is aware whenever one of these actions occur.

Is that possible without the raspberry being connected to the phone, but internet only. If not, would it be possible, while the phone has a connection to the raspberry (WLAN or Bluetooth).

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: you want an IoT device control your Phone answer and missed calls , Am I get it right ?

Comment: not like answering the phone, just getting notified, that someone is calling  at the moment or someone did call and provide the number/name of the caller

Comment: I can remember there was a Phone Call in windows UWP samples . 
That can handle phone calls , incoming and all other things related to phone calls . You can get calls using your phone app and send a notification to your other app using anyway you want (Wifi Direct , Bluetooth , over internet or any other way)

Comment: oh I did not thing about the UWP apps, I was only looking into the IOT samples here https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/

Comment: **UPDATE** The `Phone call sample` is mobile only -> https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PhoneCall